# Access nested QAbstractListModel from QML

Tags: qml, qt5, hierarchical-data, nested, qabstractlistmodel

I have a hierarchical (nested) `QAbstractListModel` in C++, i.e. the items of an `Outer` model are instances of an `Inner` model and the items of class `Inner` are some `QObject` derived `Data` instances. `Outer` has a `submodel` role for access to `Inner` items.

The corresponding QML code nests a `Repeater` inside a `ListView`.
The `ListView` properly iterates items of type `Inner` and I can retrieve the item count of `Inner` model instances in the `ListView` delegate.
The problem I have is that the `Repeater` just does not iterate over the `Data` instances of an `Inner` model.
Using debug printouts in methods of the C++ model I see that

- QML queries the `rowCount()` of instances of `Inner` but
- QML does never call `data()` on instances of `Inner`.

The QML code looks like this:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import NestedModels 1.0  as Models

ScrollView {
    width: 1980; height:600
    Component {
        id: inner
        Item {
            Text {
                x:1000; font.pointSize: 9
                text: "inner " + model.name
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: outer
        Item {
            height: 40
            property var innerModel: model.submodel
            Text {
                font.pointSize: 9
                text: "outer " + model.objectName
                + ": inner " +  innerModel
            }

            Repeater {
                model: innerModel
                delegate: inner
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
         Models.OuterModel { id: outerModel }
         model: outerModel
         delegate: outer
         Text {
             x: 200; y: 400; font.pointSize: 9
             text: outerModel.objectName + ": " + outerModel.count + " rows. " + outerModel.getItem(0)
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use separate qml file OuterDelegate.qml
I had the same issue, the problem is that you passing inner model to repeater incorrectly